# Basic arithmetic from user input in bash

Tags: bash, math, command, user-input

New to bash on my course, generally enjoying it but as soon as we've been given some coursework it's thrown a spanner in the works. 
The assignment is essentially to take an arbitrary amount of numbers from the user (using the read command), add them up, and return the result.

The previous task included a fixed amount of 10 numbers, for which i wrote:

```
#!/bin/sh


echo "Please enter 10 numbers"

read num1 
read num2 
read num3 
read num4 
read num5 
read num6 
read num7 
read num8 
read num9 
read num10


result=$((num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9 + num10))


echo The result is $result
```

Now this works fine, but I just know I'm making it harder for myself/too long, and seen as the task I'm struggling with is supposed to come from editing that script that takes 10 numbers, clearly im missing something pretty basic to take in numbers from the user & add them together without writing it 10  different times

A little guidance on user input with arbitrary numbers would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over a prompt and sum one number at a time to the total.

```
total=0
for((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
    read -p "Please enter a number: " -r num
    ((total+=num))
done
echo "The total is $total"
```

The "C-style" `for` loop syntax is a Bash extension; if you need your script to be portable to POSIX `sh` you can do something like

```
for i in $(seq 10); do
    :
```

or if you can't rely on `seq` being installed, the age-old fugly

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do
    :
    i=$(expr "$i" + 1)
done
```

Comment: `seq` isn't part of POSIX, so although the shell syntax is portable, the semantics may not be. An `while` loop that explicitly increments `i` is maximally portable.

Comment: @glennjackman I wouldn't bother with that. It requires the entire range be expanded in memory at once (which, granted, is not an issue for small ranges), and only works for fixed ranges. The C-style loop doesn't suffer from either problem.